# highchart's line chart with constant series not plotting when using linear gradient colour

Tags: highcharts

Observe the series one in the below example having a constant value and for that series points connecting lines are not plotted, but when we give a solid colour then the line will be plotted.

Highchart's line chart with constant series not plotting the line b/w points when we use line gradient colour, but if you change that to solid colour then line will be plotting.

```
highcharts.series[].data = [2, 2, 2, ...];
highcharts.color[0] = {
   linearGradient: {...},
   stop: {...}
};
```

Check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4vk7cdmz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the attribute `gradientUnits` in `linearGradient` which the default value is `objectBoundingBox`.

> Keyword objectBoundingBox should not be used when the geometry of the
>   applicable element has no width or no height, such as the case of a
>   **horizontal or vertical line**, even when the line has actual thickness
>   when viewed due to having a non-zero stroke width since stroke width
>   is ignored for bounding box calculations. When the geometry of the
>   applicable element has no width or height and objectBoundingBox is
>   specified, then the given effect (e.g., a gradient or a filter) will
>   be ignored.

[W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBox)

You need to use `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`.

Highcharts.js has fixed this issue in version 2.2.

Instead of using `linearGradient` as an object

```
"linearGradient": {
   "x1": 0,
   "y1": 0,
   "x2": 1,
   "y2": 0
}
```

, using it as an array

```
"linearGradient": [x1, y1, x2, y2],
```

will set `gradientUnits` to `userSpaceOnUse` in highcharts.js

(This requires knowledge of the line width.)

Here's a demo:

```js
var Chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'a constant series line is not plotting when using linear gradient colour.'
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 150,
    y: 100,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
  },

  colors: [{
    "linearGradient": [0, 0, 500, 0],
    "stops": [
      [0, "rgb(35,190,250)"],
      [1, "rgb(51,223,188)"]
    ]
  }, {
    "linearGradient": [0, 0, 500, 0],
    "stops": [
      [0, "rgb(250,79,168)"],
      [1, "rgb(156,120,229)"]
    ]
  }],

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday',
      'Sunday'
    ],
    plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
      from: 4.5,
      to: 6.5,
      color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
    }]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit units'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    valueSuffix: ' units'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.7/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.7/css/highcharts.css" />

<div id="container"></div>
```